# Get the list of values/entries that are common to all the columns in a dataframe (or a csv file) in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have this setup of a pandas dataframe (or a csv file):

```py
df = {
    'colA': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee'],
    'colB': ['aa', 'bb', 'dd', 'qq', 'ee'],
    'colC': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'ee', 'dd'],
    'colD': ['aa', 'bb', 'ee', 'cc', 'dd']
}
```

The goal here is to get a list/column with the set of values that appear in all the columns or in other words the entries that are common to all the columns.

Required output:

```py
col
aa
bb
dd
ee
```

or a output with the common value's list:

```py
common_list = ['aa', 'bb', 'dd', 'ee']
```

I have a silly solution (but it doesn't seem to be correct as I am not getting what I want when implemented to my dataframe)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Bus Names Concat test.csv') #i/p csv file (pandas df converted into csv)

df = df.stack().value_counts() 
core_list = df[df>2].index.tolist() #defining the common list as core list
print(len(core_list))
df_core = pd.DataFrame(core_list)

print(df_core)
```

Any help/sugggestion/feedback to get the required o/p will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case

```
s = df.melt().groupby('value')['variable'].nunique()
outlist = s[s==4].index.tolist()
Out[307]: ['aa', 'bb', 'dd', 'ee']
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what does s==4 mean and what it does? Has it to do with total number of columns in the df?

Comment: `s==4` means filtering the values that appear on exactly 4 columns (which is the number of columns you have in your example). Generally, it should be `s==len(df.columns)`

Comment: @Y.Pat see bui's comment

Comment: Thanks bui, for the clarification!

Comment: @BENY, appreciate you valuable response. I am able to obtain what I was looking for. However, the output is sorted in alphabetical order for the data I am working with, that is not desired. What I require is the exact same order as it occurs in all the 300+ columns. I looked up for some resources however unable to find a solution to this. If you may please provide some feedback regarding the outlist order that will be great. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.intersection()` method of sets to find common values between sets of each column:

```py
# wrapped in a list, take first column set and pass sets of other columns as arguments
common_list = list(set(df.colA).intersection(set(df.colB), set(df.colC), set(df.colD)))
sorted(common_list)  # needs sorting in alphabetical order
```

Output:

```py
['aa', 'bb', 'dd', 'ee']
```

Alternatively, for unspecified number of columns and without sorting:

```py
common_list = list(set(df[df.columns[0]]  # first column's set to compare the rest with
                       ).intersection(
                           *(set(df[col])  # unpack generator with sets
                             for col in df.columns[1:])))  # of the remaining columns
common_list
```

Output:

```py
['dd', 'aa', 'ee', 'bb']  # curiously enough, it is ordered differently
```

Comment: Yes, for this dummy example this would be great. However, for the data I am working with, it has 300+ columns. Also, I must clarify that the order needed is not alphabetical but the order in which it appears in the columns. Can you please provide an alternative feedback? thanks!

Comment: @Y.Pat sure, I added these suggestions to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Transpose the dataframe so columns are rows and rows are columns.

Convert the values to a list of lists.

Map each sublist as a Set and unpack the Intersection of the Sets to a List of unique values.

```
common_list = list(set.intersection(*map(set, df.values.transpose().tolist())))
print(common_list)

['aa', 'bb', 'dd', 'ee']
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory text to help OP understand the reasoning behind the code